# MongoDB legal age query

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with an age variable (integer). Each document in my collection represents a user and their age as well as other identifying data. If the user has an age that is 18+ then I need to limit the results of the query to documents that also have 18+ as the age, nobody under 18. On the contrary If the user is under 18 years of age then they should also be able to only view other users who have an age under 18. How could I turn this idea into a db.collection.find() query ??? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`$gte`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/) for 18+:

```
db.collection.find({age: {$gte: 18}})
```

And [`$lt`](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/lt/) for under 18:

```
db.collection.find({age: {$lt: 18}})
```

Comment: Is it possible with a single find() or do i need to do an if statement on the age before querying

Comment: Yes, you need to use an `if` statement before querying.